# LinkedIn WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api, linkedin-plugins

I have the LinkedIn plug in and I set it up to auto post only a specific category of blog posts. On it's first run it posted both of the blog posts - the category I had specified and one I did not specify. How can I get it to only post one particular category of blog posts? In the Settings, In "Select categories for auto publish" I only selected one category... help! thanks. I sent this question to LinkedIn and they sent me here.

Comment: LinkedIn sent you here for support with their plugin? It's impossible to help unless you tell us _exactly_ which plugin you have.  There appears to be multiple LinkedIn plugins - how about a URL to the plugin on the WP repo?  (example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-linkedin/ )

Comment: Yeah it seemed weird to me to have to go here... anyway my plugin is https://wordpress.org/plugins/linkedin-auto-publish/  thanks!

Comment: DELETED THIS PLUGIN - it's useless and ZERO support. no response here, LinkedIn or Developer.  Trying this one instead: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-linkedin-auto-publish/